# Incorrect result returning by end_with? ruby method

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to check for images src in a HTML img tag using following code

```
extension.end_with?(/[.jpg|.gif|.png|.jpeg]/).should eq(true)
```

where
    extension = "teaser_image610x450.jpg"

I also tried

```
 extension.end_with?(/[.]jpg|gif|png|jpeg/).should eq(true)
```

In both cases I am getting FALSE.
What is wrong with above code ?

Comment: The first case is wrong, because you use wrong syntax for grouping `()` instead of `[]`. I'm curious about the 2nd case, though.

Comment: Seems like `end_with?` doesn't takes a Regex. Please check the relevant documentation to confirm. See this link and check out the source of `end_with?` - http://extensions.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/String.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following form:

```
extension.end_with?(".jpg",".gif",".png",".jpeg")
```

Or, something like this:

```
extensions = [".jpg",".gif",".png",".jpeg"]
if extensions.include?(extension)
  # do something here
end
```

I never saw this method being used with a regex before.